# Shifiting xmm integer register values using non-AVX instructions on Intel x86 architecture

Tags: c++, x86, simd, intrinsics, sse2

I have the following problem which I need to solve using anything other than AVX2.

I have 3 values stored in a m128i variable (the 4th value is not needed ) and need to shift those values by 4,3,5. I need two functions. One for the right logical shift by those values and another for the left logical shift.

Does anyone know a solution to the problem using SSE/AVX ? The only thing I could find was `_mm_srlv_epi32()` which is AVX2.

To add a little more information. Here is the code I am trying to optimize using SSE/AVX. It's part of  my draughts/checkers -engine.

```
uint32_t Board::getMoversBlack(){
    const uint32_t nocc=~(BP|WP);
    const uint32_t BK = BP & K;
    uint32_t movers = (nocc >> 4) & BP;
    movers |= ((nocc & MASK_R3) >>3) & BP;
    movers |= ((nocc & MASK_R5) >>5) & BP;
    if (BK != 0) {
        movers |= (nocc << 4) & BK;
        movers |= ((nocc & MASK_L3) << 3) & BK;
        movers |= ((nocc & MASK_L5) <<5) & BK;
    }
    return movers;
}
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are there any assumptions you can make, for instance that the integers fit in 30 bits? Otherwise, shift right by 3, multiply by {2,4,1,0}, shift right by 2. Left shift is a single _mm_mullo_epi32.

Comment: @MarcGlisse To add a litte information. I am working on a checkers engine and the int's are simple bitBoad representation of the current board state (the 1's are occupied by a piece). Therefore, I can not make the assumption you mentioned

Comment: Ideally you could store your data in vectors with 4 separate boards per vector, instead of different stuff about each board in one vector.  Then you avoid horizontal operations, and maybe needing stuff like this.  This might not be practical if you need to branch on something from a single vector the way you have them laid out now, or other reasons, but worth mentioning.  (This is the same reason it's usually worse to implement 3D direction vectors as SIMD vectors `{x,y,z, unused}` instead of using 3 separate arrays of x, y, and z data so you have `{x0,x1,x2,x3}`,etc. for 4 points at once.

Comment: If you really need this, your options are doing separate shifts and then blending, or doing what @Marc suggested.  His suggestion is probably a good once (and does work even with no assumptions: note the right-shift by 3 before the multiply to implement variable left shift.)  But note that **SSE4.1** `_mm_mullo_epi32` is not fast: 2 uops for p0 on Haswell: 10c latency and one per 2c throughput.  (better throughput on Skylake.  Better latency on pre-Haswell where `pmulld` is a single-uop instruction.  On AMD Bulldozer-family and Ryzen, latency = 4 or 5, throughput = one per 2c.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I coded up the pmulld trick for variable shifts with intrinsics.  In the OP's case (with a don't-care 4th element), it probably still wins vs. separate shifts + blend (with `movss` and `movsd`), but a version with 3 shifts is surprisingly cheap (not a lot of extra instructions to copy and blend).  It probably sucks significantly more with a 4th element.  But it and an SSE2 version of your idea are maybe usable.

Comment: It is classical example where any vectorization should not be attempted as a vectorized code is less performant than current one.

Comment: Looks great for vectorization, but only if you run 4 iterations of it in parallel, instead of trying to use horizontal operations within *one* iteration.  Horizontal OR takes too much shuffling.  (2 shuffles and 2 OR instructions.)  Hint, OR the the shift results together and `& BK` or `& BP` that once before `|=` into `movers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need this (and can't avoid it by rearranging your data), You can fully/safely emulate `_mm_srlv_epi32` without clobbering any high or low bits.

For compile-time constant counts, you can use a mix of left and right shifts with most of these.

Probably bad options:

- Unpack to scalar: yuck.  Kinda bad for compile-time constant counts, but even worse for runtime-variable counts, especially if you'd have to unpack a vector of counts.  x86 variable-count shifts without BMI2 `shrx` have clunky semantics and decode to multiple uops on Intel SnB-family.  They also take extra `mov` instructions to put the shift count in `cl` if it wasn't already there.
- Do separate shifts and then blending to take the element from the vector that was shifted by that amount.  This isn't great, but you might be able to reduce the cost of blending by zeroing the unwanted elements as you copy them.  (e.g. if the high element is known to be zero, copy with `pshufd` to get a vector of `{0,22,0,0}` from a starting vector of `{11,22,33, 0}`, and repeat for `{0,0,33,0}`.)

  So, zero the high element that you're not using, 2x pshufd to copy+shuffle zeros into place, 3x psrld with different counts, AND out the other elements in the vector you didn't copy, then OR the 3 vectors back together.  (This takes more work if you aren't leaving one element of your vector unused.)

  Depending on the rest of your code, and the microarchitecture, using a shuffle instead of MOVDQA+PAND might not be worth it.  If any elements use the same shift count, this option becomes more attractive.

  Also, you can blend the low element into a vector with `movss`, and blend the low half with `movsd`.  Those use the shuffle port, so shuffle throughput could be a problem.  This might actually be pretty solid.

---

**Hopefully better options.**

- The SSE2 version of Marc's suggestion (see below) also works in the fully general case.
- **When the difference between smallest and largest shift count is <= the smallest shift count, you can [use @Marc's SSE4.1 suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993981/shifiting-xmm-integer-register-values-using-non-avx-instructions-on-intel-x86-ar#comment80935200_46993981)** to use multiply as a variable left-shift to account for the differences in right-shift counts.  Or on its own as a left-shift.   This is probably the best for most cases, taking many fewer instructions even though vector-int multiply is slow.

```
__m128i srlv435_sse4(__m128i v)
{
    __m128i rshift = _mm_srli_epi32(v, 3);   // v >> 3
    // differences in shift count by multiplying by powers of 2
    __m128i vshift = _mm_mullo_epi32(rshift, _mm_setr_epi32(2,4,1,0)); // [ x >> 2,  y >> 1, z >> 3, 0 ]  Except with low bits truncated.
    __m128i shift2 = _mm_srli_epi32(vshift, 2);                        // [ x >> 4,  y >> 3, z >> 5, 0 ]
     return shift2;
}
```

This is nice because it operates in-place without the compiler needing any MOVDQA instructions to copy registers, even without AVX1.

Note that **SSE4.1** `_mm_mullo_epi32` is not fast: 2 uops for p0 on Haswell: 10c latency and one per 2c throughput.  Better throughput on Skylake where each of the 2 uops can can run on p0 or p1, but still dependent with 10c latency.  (http://agner.org/optimize/ and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

This has better latency on pre-Haswell where `pmulld` is a single-uop instruction (~5 cycles, 1c throughput) instead of 2 dependent uops for 10 cycles.

On AMD Bulldozer-family and Ryzen, latency = 4 or 5, throughput = one per 2c for pmulld.

I didn't check on port conflicts with vector shifts.

---

**Without SSE4.1**, you can use 2x SSE2 `_mm_mul_epu32` to do 2 multiplies at a time.  To line up the odd elements (1 and 3), `pshufd` to copy+shuffle them down to positions 0 and 2 where `pmuludq` looks for them.

That produces 2 64-bit results from the even 2 32-bit elements, so you don't need to pre-shift to avoid overflow.  It also means its safe to use when the difference between shift counts is larger than the minimum shift, so the SSE4.1 way couldn't keep all the required bits in the element with the most kept bits.

```
// general case: substitute in *any* shift counts and it still works.
__m128i srlv_sse2(__m128i v)  // [x  y  z  w]
{
    __m128i vs_even = _mm_mul_epu32(v, _mm_setr_epi32(1U<<1, 1U<<2, 1U<<0, 0));    // [ x<<1    z<<0 ]  (64-bit elements)
    // The 4 (1U<<2) is unused, but this lets us share a constant with the SSE4 version, saving rodata size.  (Compilers optimize duplicate constants for you; check the disassembly for same address)
    vs_even = _mm_srli_epi64(vs_even, 5);  // [ x>>4  0   x>>5  0 ]  (32-bit elements ready for blending with just an OR)

    __m128i odd = _mm_shuffle_epi32(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 1, 1));
    __m128i vs_odd =  _mm_mul_epu32(v, _mm_setr_epi32(1U<<(32-3),0,0,0));    // [ (y<<32) >> 3    0 ]  (64-bit elements)

    // If any elements need left shifts, you can't get them all the way out the top of the high half with a 32-bit power of 2.
    //vs_odd = _mm_slli_epi64(vs_odd, 32 - (3+2));       // [ garbage,  y>>3,  0, 0 ]

    // SSE2 doesn't have blend instructions, do it manually.
    __m128i vs_oddhi = _mm_and_si128(vs_odd, _mm_setr_epi32(0, -1, 0, -1));
    __m128i shifted = _mm_or_si128(vs_even, vs_oddhi);

     return shifted;
}
```

There are some obvious optimizations here:

Your case isn't using the 4th element, so the 2nd multiply is pointless: just shift and use an AND mask to clear the high element.  `vs_odd = _mm_srli_epi32v, 3);` and use `0,-1,0,0` as your AND mask.

Instead of a left-shift by 1 and 0, add x to itself and leave z unmodified.  Copying a vector with zeroing of the upper 64 bits is very cheap (`movq`), but not as cheap as `movdqa` (on CPUs with mov-elimination).

```
    __m128i rshift = _mm_srli_epi32(v, 3);         // v >> 3
    __m128i xy00   = _mm_move_epi64(rshift);
    __m128i vshift = _mm_add_epi32(rshift, xy00);       // [ x >> 2,  y >> 2, z >> 3, 0 ]
```

But this doesn't handle `y`.  We could isolate `y>>2` from `vshift` and add it again to produce `y>>1`.  (But remember not to use the old `y>>3` from `xy00`).

We could also consider using `_mm_mul_epu32` (`pmuludq`) once and a copy+shift+AND for the other step (copy from the original `v` instead of `rshift` to shorten the dep chain).  This is useful in your case because you're not using the top element, so there's only one valid odd element and you thus don't need a  variable shift.

With a combination of `movq`, `movss`, and `movsd`, there might be something more to gain here from basically shifting the 3 elements separately.  There are tradeoffs between port pressure, latency, uop count (front-end throughput) and whatnot.  e.g. I'm thinking

```
movdqa  xmm1, xmm0
psrld   xmm0, 3        #  [ x>>3  y>>3    garbage ]
psrld   xmm1, 4        #  [ x>>4  y>>4    garbage ] 
movss   xmm1, xmm0     #  [ x>>3  y>>4    garbage ]   # FP shuffle

psrld   xmm0, 2        #  [ garbage        z>>5 ]
movsd   xmm0, xmm1     #  [ x>>3  y>>4     z>>5 ]     # FP shuffle
```

Haswell for example only has 1 shift per clock throughput, so this isn't wonderful.  It has pretty good latency though, compared to the multiply options.  It's good on Skylake where 2 ports can run vector immediate shifts.

FP shuffles between integer instructions is fine on Intel CPUs other than Nehalem (where it's a 2-cycle bypass-delay latency penalty each way, but throughput is still ok).  I think it's fine on AMD as well.

Of course all those CPUs have SSE4.1, so if you use dynamic runtime dispatch the SSE2 version only has to work on Core2 / K10.  (And I guess older Atom, or whatever).

[code + asm output on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSBnVAV2OUxAHIBSAJgGY8AO2QAbZlgDU3fgGE8AWwXCCxYQDoEM7NwAMAQT36A%2BsYW1eADjySGxUQDcALPwCsxhg0xOIp81ZsHAEojbgB2ACEjSRjJPwtrSWIGBDwAMwJpfgAROKUPezxjTAAHPH5eCAdSSX4Q/gjYgHomyQcsnX5sWujm1vw0tMxiTBFMBklhW1SMyTRmIUyAIwBPSQVmUQI8EtEV4WBJVckS1AB3YYnUNMleXpj4gLaU9MyZXLMFM03RVGKyioQZIzAg1T4eTCqf7lSq8UhOUj0XRBeqNFrSVyNAAeHW0txqkjW2jx9EkAC9cV1ajVdBjcpJsFj2CVMmdCAhJL8zkdCBNVAtkABDAiYdDqe5xMwJGwvDK8LIffJ2URFUowqqy0G3VGxXV6/X69HcTGSHHEqkImJErp4/g1Cnm7quGl0iVJSGsITTV53BqhMLZUIGdHAUbDQWiOaCrwgWzMJYMbYEZgiyZegBUgqEK3T3tm80WEyz6EmmUTeFEkbOJAA1gxxQZHollQ4PF5Kk3AkEYkbMTjCTEKZIzsbAwZwlEDLrO89ig5Rgq8l8NqJ/sxAdUlxCoWrAbQAKoyWRH0kHo9HuGSM9yI%2B6GkomSNPoY7HnuS0XVkt%2ByWmjmIQAA2JwAFolkISRMFETAFFGAgGBCKdnwAFQQTBJCcSQIGvY85F4bs8AmBZmC8dAaiWFNJAIVIJiguDJGI6ZBRGSRBTmVAhETLNWXZSjUMkABlfjsAw%2BdkjwdiagYQUHAOJIMGFViGDwMlMHUf9ZFQBQyig5JJFQFlFGUtD0GYXY8CFVM0A4gguImNISEJFhHzmVDkBrXjjII6MvAUJY9kkeziFsQUYJY9B0BGTwEP0XUHAYOcF3eLdlVVMogI1BKhBqVwdUkXtXxtLoMMkWkYixR1XBiX9XHpCAKlA8DIOg2CJhGQV0DWQKjigoR8CEQ42SoyQqGIzIs0kAB5AAlaKJRnDASyS8EUmYQYoOhDcwQAWS24x%2BIACX3AAxI6ABlsDqmo7SvGpaAfP1EIeKUnji4wFsXLcVzXTbkshYgNsqbCjzq3hgLqUg70h%2B6nx7VpjUaCAVm/Cpu0dWpdWq2qgIazImpgwtZsevLWgASRuLM1jxlrJCETBRU5TBZk1BgahWFgoyEMBOEyUNMio6CWMrDzh0FNYWD5viiBKPSbn5yRUmADkEAjG5Bo5Vj6rAzJTguILrluBsYr6V73qWpVK1SvB0pN8KrvlYDMP4PgIjw3K9XyyRgCYpZBVDAkkcK7BrpKl1RyDI3YYEoT5XQVBxk57n5ektC/NGEthETYhmGQbZ2JZyRY9LdYs2YCM9kN6dnsSG30FSRdwWLDw8ASDKFrBJU/oBiA70kYDSR7vvobmquZRBemza%2BEgm5b17MHnLLZwW1JUXDvURmTYgvU1UVH39MdDHHAR0hK8P0QWNJhAI1D06waMjBnFsXHcTxMA7Ee2m7YmX37NZyRiEcar%2BknBHSU/hEhkk1PXJUhQu6bhys5A0z54ae29r7TANQvbEB9n7P%2BaNnQoKwWg1044iYzmBK8KBXwUqwKum7RBHtyqB2ugHToQcagyCOhwjhxCD4gPREdEmAANLa2BYxUQIpMCYPs3JnCYugfOFwRaLAHNvEsUFPCSVQNIUh78sTtRLDECeZhUDzmhOlchGQV46LATYLEKxIFGP0V3CxWo9HhTdgwx0l4WHaGulw/gnCAk8LdAaOxDicjJRgbuSoYSQS3ToZ4phrNHR%2BICf4o6PDibLSICMDw6BV6xHXp6U09iQS72DOmYeNiSm6FKpQ4xrY1TWysSAmccUQT1KcdEqoNQ7G1LoUgk0ZpA74itJSbol4HQjOupjKp0oBx6kcb1aeVgIB9J7stTu3SB793vC0xBsVwmKi%2BF0gElR2mvFZgMhh4zRkDjRqSKZrDqQlWCdY%2BZmp5RGOod0i5GQah4QQZHZBwznmWnudM%2B0tz8GzKJu6DeW8QS%2BmAXqdMTQ97hz4PwNO6ROBBFIKILgrhOCkCEFwXQJLUBcGPLwKItLbAsDYGhLFtASUEHJXi/FNYQD8EsOofguh%2BAAVoAATgAgBVwugnCuBFXaQlnAnAkrJZwClpAqWcBJQwEAd52UqrxaQOAsAkBoC0hWYY5BKAmu0sMEAwAwhwgvlsS4lAlgctIGBIQTEVhcFZaQE1%2BMCATSEHsN1WAFBZmAFBUNeARg5zwPOLVerSCYCxJgZAKYOCcF9SoSCPq2VqAUHm/FKoEzwHxfpXOHEuDASZL3RM%2BScjACEMwEVIre4AHUy69wmvwXuChky03eAwGsKxRCChrGhYCCgX4YSnZ4Lw/BNWMvYHQYtRKlVuvVViSwAFgJAU9sgZAkgwjqHlBAXAhAHIspqBpU1OlpACDumyjlKJSDcqsPygCAqnBhFqbQACvBdBhFcGEAlXBFWks3VwTV2rSC6opfiw1iAUCaWtWQCgEArVmuICgMd/VJV3kdSKZILq3Ueq9Xmv1mkA1BpDUmsNEao30ZjWm7YCa3UprTRmyjOb5W%2BtUIoItBK8ClsgOWgyedq21uAvW94TaW1tuAp2oWwEe19oHZgIdI6x0TpiHOrwEGmCsBXXdMDnBiWQaTVunde6MJiAjZIVw6hdDOcwhenJD7%2BCklvWhzzeFn16tfdy/g/B%2BUhfCxFiLZmIPKtVeqmDOqX1rs4LwDdVnoNwaS6QUSSl2IgCcEAA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: Unfortunately all of the shown methods are not performant since their cost is equal or greater  to non vectorized code - it is an antipatern what in this case means vectorization should not be attempted at all

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski: The OP is using this as part of a larger algorithm so the inputs are already in vectors, and the output needs to be in vectors.  (Hopefully the OP's other code is more SSE2-friendly).  If you think you can do better than any of these by unpacking to scalar and then re-inserting into vectors, go ahead.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski: Did you actually benchmark or analyze any of these in detail?  On Haswell, the one using movss and movsd to merge should have a throughput of one vector per 3 clocks (bottlenecked on `psrld` throughput.)  That's as good as you can do with scalar if the data was in memory (for what you might be thinking of, where this is *all* you're doing looping over a big array).  The SSE4.1 version has a throughput of one per 2 clocks on Skylake (4 p01 uops), same as the 3x psrld+movss+movsd version on Skylake (p5 bottleneck)

Comment: First of all there is no info in question or comments to the question that code is already in vectors and output needs to be in vectors - so it is impossible to make this assumption based on information provided. Second - why do you use SSE on Haswell or Skylake. There are better shift intrinsics available via AVX2 ISA extensions.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski: The OP shows the whole function they're trying to optimize, which includes some `|` and `&` operators.  HSW and SKL are relevant for SSE2 or SSE4 if the OP doesn't implement run-time dispatching and instead just vectorizes for a baseline instruction set.  SnB/IvB are in the same boat as Haswell as far as throughput for some of these options, because they also only have one *fp* shuffle unit.  The 2nd shuffle unit is integer only.  On Core2 (last Intel CPU without SSE4.2), `movss` merging is very good: it's an integer-domain shuffle with 0.33c throughput.

Comment: Even with all this arguments there is still one major problem -> unaligned load and store. For me the whole point about vectorization is to get faster code and as far as this cannot be proven vectorization should be avoided. Furthermore the are possibilities to improve code by using 64 bit arithmetic for 32 bit operands - recommended by Agner's optimization manuals as well.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski: Where do you see any unaligned loads/stores?  The OP is padding with a dummy element to make 16B chunks of data.  That's basically irrelevant anyway, for future readers the question is just about emulating `_mm_srlv_epi32`.  With SSE4.1, you can do it with one per 3 clock throughput on Sandybridge (for constant shift counts; shift and `pmulld` all compete for p0) vs. Haswell's 2 per clock throughput for `vpsrlvd` (3 uops, 2p0 1p5).  It's not until Skylake that variable-shifts are really efficient.

Comment: So the question is worth answering whether or not the OP's use-case turns out to vectorize well.  For constant shift counts, it's definitely not a show-stopper for vectorization.  It's definitely something to avoid though (e.g. in this case by running 4 `getMoversBlack()` functions in parallel instead of trying to do horizontal stuff *within* one XMM vector.)

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski: 64-bit for 32; you SWAR with a pair of 32-bit integers in a 64-bit register?  Yeah that might be useful here, but you need to mask after shifts to clear bits that crossed from one half into the other.  You might be able to defer that instead of ANDing after *every* shift, though.

Answer (score -1):

SSE2 Intel Architecture Instruction Set Extensions introduced shift operations for integers. Below I have inserted a list of available compiler intrinsics implementing logical shift operations in SSE2:

```
psllw
__m128i _mm_sll_epi16 (__m128i a, __m128i count)

pslld
__m128i _mm_sll_epi32 (__m128i a, __m128i count)

psllq
__m128i _mm_sll_epi64 (__m128i a, __m128i count)

psllw
__m128i _mm_slli_epi16 (__m128i a, int imm8)

pslld
__m128i _mm_slli_epi32 (__m128i a, int imm8)

psllq
__m128i _mm_slli_epi64 (__m128i a, int imm8)

pslldq
__m128i _mm_slli_si128 (__m128i a, int imm8)

psrlw
__m128i _mm_srl_epi16 (__m128i a, __m128i count)

psrld
__m128i _mm_srl_epi32 (__m128i a, __m128i count)

psrlq
__m128i _mm_srl_epi64 (__m128i a, __m128i count)

psrlw
__m128i _mm_srli_epi16 (__m128i a, int imm8)

psrld
__m128i _mm_srli_epi32 (__m128i a, int imm8)

psrlq
__m128i _mm_srli_epi64 (__m128i a, int imm8)

psrldq
__m128i _mm_srli_si128 (__m128i a, int imm8)
```

More information is available on [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) website.

If limitation of the above intrinsics shifting all values by the same number of bits does not suit everyone it is possible to use multiplication by power of 2 and division by power of 2, however, this would have major impact on performance and most probably right shifting 3 32-bit integers each by different value will be faster than vector division. The same could be true for multiplication, however, first I would test it in code.

Comment: Those all shift every element by the same count though.

Comment: That's what you got - probable it's necessary to preprocess arguments before using those.

Comment: Those intrinsics do shift by the same count. I need to shift the values stored individually by different counts

Comment: I have edited answer to include explanation of your problem. Unfortunately this is what you get below AVX2.