# Shift right every DW in a __m128i by a different amount

Tags: sse, simd

I want to shift right every element of a __m128i register by a different amount.I know this is possible by multiplication if we want to shift left like below:

```
__m128i mul_constant = _mm_set_epi32(8, 4, 2, 1);
__m128i left_vshift = _mm_mullo_epi32(R, mul_constant);
```

But, what is the solution if we want to shift it right?

Comment: They added the variable-length shift in AVX2. But I guess you need this for older processors?

Comment: @Mysticial Yes. I need a SSE3-4 instruction.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Shifiting xmm integer register values using non-AVX instructions on Intel x86 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46993981/253056) and [Shifting 4 integers right by different values SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38363423/253056) and [SSE2 shift by vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38605451/253056).

Comment: @HadiRanjbar: If you need a non-AVX answer, why did you tag this with `[avx]`?  Do you also want an AVX2 `vpsrlvd` answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shifting 4 integers right by different values SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363423/shifting-4-integers-right-by-different-values-simd)

Comment: @PaulR: heh, I was amused to find that I'd answered all 3 of those duplicates you found :P  And two of them were *very* similar to each other, mostly just leaving one of the 4 elements unused.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, I got a bad case of déjà vu when this question came up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it like below:
Shifting every byte by a different amount to left and then a 32-bit right shift by 3 gave me what I wanted.

```
 R = _mm_mullo_epi32(R, _mm_set_epi32(1, 2, 4, 8));
 R = _mm_srli_epi32(R, 3);
```